# Suggestions for Automating apps on Samsung Tizen OS TV device

Tags: ui-automation, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am looking for suggestion around is there a technical way to automate apps on real Samsung TV device that is based out of Tizen operating system.

I want to do test UI Automation similar to Appium on android space.

Comment: You can check https://suite.st/